# How to activate an existing View in Catel.MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel

How to activate an existing View in Catel? `IUIVisualizerService.Show()` always create a new View. I am currently using the following code in ViewModel, which is not nice since it is dependent on Window.

```
private void ShowSomethingExecute() {
  var uiVisualizerService =  this.GetDependencyResolver().Resolve<IUIVisualizerService>();
  var viewManager = this.GetServiceLocator().ResolveType<IViewManager>();

  var testView = viewManager.GetFirstOrDefaultInstance(typeof(TestView));
  if (testView == null) {
    uiVisualizerService.Show(new TestViewModel());
  } else {
    (testView as Window)?.Activate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to re-activate a window in the current version. But the good news is that everything is pluggable / replaceable in Catel so you can easily provide your own version that supports this feature.

*Or you could create a PR and support this in Catel as well ;-)*

Comment: Thanks. I guess a PR would require a change in IUIVisualizerService by adding overloads for Show() and ShowDialog(). Would that be OK?

Comment: I think in CreateWindow (see https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.Shared/Services/UIVisualizerService.cs#L423), you can check if we already have a view with this vm alive. If so, return that. In the classes using that, you can use Activate instead of Show.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a `bool activateIfExists` parameter to `Show()`. If it's `true`, then activate if window exists. If it's `false`, always create new window like the current behavior.

Comment: If you want you can create an issue at the issue tracker, that's easier to discuss that StackOverflow.